# Behavior of user folders (the folders under `Library`)

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions

The context of this post is somewhat related to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1355351/pictures-folders-under-c-users-user-not-syncing-with-pictures-library) but far more elaborate. It all started with the following alert from *OneDrive*:

[image]

1. If you hover over the name of any folder, it shows the path as

   ```
   {drive-letter}:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\Documents\
   ```

   > [image]
2. However, in reality, this conflicts with the contents of the properties tab:

   ```
   {drive-letter}:\Users\{username}\
   ```

   Also, this time they don't have those fancy 'My' prefix in their names.

   [image]
3. Moreover, there is no "My Music", "My Pictures" or "My Videos" folder in the directory `{drive-letter}:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\Documents\`. Which contradicts point no 1. Also if you try to access these folders, the following dialog box appears:

   [image]

   instead of something similar to this one:

   [image]
4. So, I try to access them from the command line (PowerShell without admin) and this is what happens:

   [image]

   No error to be seen and I am able to make changes inside the folder.
   And the changes also appear here:

   [image]

   Which proves that `{drive-letter}:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\Documents\{My whatever}` and `{drive-letter}:\Users\{username}\{whatever}` is the same directory.
5. Being intended to fix the *OneDrive* error message issue, I moved the folder inside `{drive-letter}:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\`. At this point, the system identifies it as a regular folder and automatically creates a duplicate of them. Because of which the error message still remains.

So, I basically want to fix the access issue described in point no 3 which, I believe, will prevent the message from appearing. Is there any way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries are not folders. They are an index of the contents of select folders. "What's the difference?" The difference, in practical terms, is that you can add files to the libraries that are in different folders. They do not exist anywhere on the hard drive (not as a folder anyway) and you will not be able to find a path to them. Libraries exist here and only here:

[image]

By default the libraries have the `C:\Users\<username>\` and the `OneDrive\` folders that share their names as the only folders they are indexing the contents of.

[image]

This is why changing the content of one of these user folders will result in matching changes in the associated library. However, if you right-click on a different folder you will see an `Include in library` submenu with options matching the library names. This allows you to add the contents of this additional folder to the library. This is useful if, for example, you have a 3rd party application that does not store it's content files in the folders provided by Windows. Once you have added another folder to a given library you will find that the contents of both folders are shown together in that library as if the contents were all in the same folder... even though they are not.

Another thing you need to understand is that the `My -` folders are also, technically, not folders. And they definitely are not your libraries.

What the `My -` folders are is called a "junction" which is conceptually similar to a *nix style "symlink". It is basically a file that applications are expected to treat as if it was a folder that exists somewhere else on the harddrive. This makes a single folder look as if it was in two places when, in fact, one of them is actually a junction. For example, `D:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Pictures` points to `D:\Users\<username>\Pictures`.

Windows vista and newer use these `My -` junctions to maintain backwards compatibility with the file system layout used in Windows XP. The idea is that if an application which expects a XP-style file layout attempts to access the `My -` folders it will actually be accessing the folders those junctions point to. However, because these particular junctions are only there for backwards compatibility, users are blocked from accessing them directly and they are typically flagged as "hidden" so the user will not get confused by them. Hence the error you receive when you try to access them.

Based on what else you have said, it seems that you somehow have ended up with a junction or symlink (Vista and newer support both) from `OneDrive\Documents` to `D:\Users\<username>\Documents`. This is not how it's supposed to be. OneDive's Documents folder is supposed to be a completely separate folder from the one in `C:\Users\<username>\`. I believe this is the root cause of your problems. However, because it is unclear how this happened it is unsafe to attempt to revert it. The cause of this anomaly needs to be identified first so as not to break something else while trying to fix what is, ultimately, only an annoyance.

Comment: Excuse me, Mr @CliffArmstrong, how did the Git folder end up in your library?

Comment: I use a program called TortoiseGit. It added the library. It does not, however, add anything to the library by default. I honestly never use the feature so I'm not that familiar with it.